# Profile | more | Use - Listing - Mode not working

Tags: contacts, profile

I have a profile that used to work to allow members to search our contact list.
Now when we use it even from the CiviCRM profile list it brings up a wordpress page
.../civicrm/?q=civicrm%2Fprofile&gid=14&reset=1 that only says

CiviCRM

Do not delete this page. Page content is generated by CiviCRM.

I get same if I try the create mode or the edit mode options under more, but the URL has
2Fcreate or 2Fedit rather than 2Fprofile.

Comment: What versions of civi / wp?

Comment: I am using CiviCRM 5.22.1. with WP 5.5.1 and Running PHP version: 7.3.20